# Collaborate on wordpress local website, share files via dropbox?

Tags: plugins, database, shared-hosting

How can one share and sync files of a WordPress website with users that can edit (collaborate on) the website locally on their own instance?

Can Dropbox be used to share the WordPress website files and database data? If so which directories should be shared? Or should one use a Distributed version control system like Mercurial to do this?

I think if the files are shared than there will be a copy of WordPress database files for each user. The website is under local development and is not hosted with WordPress .

Can multiple user accounts be used on the shared WordPress files or just a single user account is allowed to edit the WordPress website?

Also what about plugins, can they be shared with its contents for a WordPress website?

Comment: You can share files anyway you want, they are just files, the database data can be shared like a file if you export it, because it's a file. Using revision control when sharing files is a good idea.

Comment: Ok. But in wordpress which is the directory for a particular website? How do I know the directory of the website I would like to share? And how do I know which database files or tables   are for a website in wordpress? I can then share those directories/files with users accordingly.

Comment: I guess files outside WordPress directory like the WAMP or MAMP files for the local server stack do not need to be shared for collaboration on a WordPress website from different local instances?

Comment: Any responses on this please?